# Flash ActionScript 3 - is there a memory leak in this function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory-management

I'm getting to grips with memory allocation (and ActionScript 3 in general) and I came across a function like this in a tutorial:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void
{

if(redClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(redClip.x, redClip.y),255,blueClipBmpData,new Point(blueClip.x, blueClip.y),255))

trace("hit");

}
```

The part I am worried about is the 'new Point...' bit in the hitTest function. So, every time the function is called, new memory is being allocated to store a Point object.

Because there are no references to the Point (like var a: Point = new Point(...)) does that mean the garbage collector will free the memory for 'new Point' after the function is called?

Would it be better to write it something like:

```
var a:Point = new Point();
```

outside the enterFrame function, then within the enterFrame function write:

```
a.x = redClip.x

a.y = redClip.y
```

So that you are re-using the memory the variable refers to?

Please correct me if my tentative understanding of memory is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GC won't immediately reclaim the memory after the function has executed, but the Point objects will be eligible for garbage collection whenever the sweep occurs.  The Flash GC reclaims memory when it needs to.

You could declare the Point object outside of the function so that only one is ever created, but then you have to remember to destroy any reference to it when you're done with it.  I think that any efficiency gain would be marginal.

Comment: I'd take up the latter point for the sake of cleanliness anyway. Seems sloppy to me having a new object created every frame.

Comment: @MartyWallace, just to argue for the other side. Creating an external reusable `Point` introduces a maintenance pain point; as well as the possibility for bugs when things get more complicated. We get more flexibility when we minimize shared state; it's just one more thing to worry about when refactoring code -- and for what benefit, a negligible to non-existant performance gain? Not saying there isn't a time and a place to do this though! ;)

Comment: It's not so much for the performance gain.. The concept of creating a new object over and over just seems really messy in my mind. Besides, it's not that hard to create a `deconstruct` function or something at the end of your class and cover off all of these things.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification shanethehat. It's good to know that those points will get cleaned up. Just out of curiosity, does anyone know roughly big is a Point object is (it's got 3 numbers and a couple of functions in its class) and at what rate (per second?) the garbage collector comes around?